# Sanity start command not finding the module 'node:path"

Tags: reactjs, sanity

So I am running a react application and trying to install a sanity studio along with it. However after typing

`npm create sanity@latest`

naming my sanity folder skwstudio

then commanding
`cd skwstudio`
and
`sanity start`

I get
`
Error: Cannot find module 'node:path'
Require stack:

- C:/Users/--/Desktop/saskwebdev/skwstudios/node_modules/vite/dist/node-cjs/publicUtils.cjs
- C:/Users/--/Desktop/saskwebdev/skwstudios/node_modules/vite/index.cjs
- C:/Users/--/Desktop/saskwebdev/skwstudios/node_modules/@sanity/server/lib/index.js
- C:/Users/--/Desktop/saskwebdev/skwstudios/node_modules/sanity/lib/_chunks/previewAction-b80a2deb.js
- C:/Users/--/Desktop/saskwebdev/skwstudios/node_modules/sanity/lib/_chunks/_internal-ca5bebdb.js
- C:/Users/--/Desktop/saskwebdev/skwstudios/node_modules/sanity/lib/_internal.js
- C:/Users/--/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@sanity/cli/lib/_chunks/getCliConfig-b55cef48.js
- C:/Users/--/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@sanity/cli/lib/_chunks/cli-0bbdf4ec.js
- C:/Users/--/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@sanity/cli/lib/run.js
- C:/Users/--/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity
  at Object. (C:/Users/--/Desktop/saskwebdev/skwstudios/node_modules/vite/dist/node-cjs/publicUtils.cjs:5:14)
  `

I have tried deleting node_modules and commanding
`npm install` and `sanity install` but I get the same error. Any idea as to what is going on?

Comment: Do you have an old node version?

Comment: I can check and see....

Comment: Looks like my version  is 14.17.0 and the current is 18.12.1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my version of node was outdated. Upgrading it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

****Follow these steps:****

1. npm install -g @sanity/cli
2. sanity init
3. create a project and logging Google or whatever you like.
4. select a project to use
5. your project name
6. select project template
7. after npm install
8. npm run dev